# What happens (behind the scene) when we create a blank folder?

Tags: filesystems, operating-systems

Let's start with **Windows with NTFS**. I'm just curious what happens when we create a new blank `Folder`. I'm actually more curious on **how (where) a blank folder information is stored** (or) how much of space does it take.

Does it still take space? *(Even though i roughly know it does take)* How much of size is used, and where is that information stored? (Does "Windows" use the "Registry" to store this information? Or so called, "Master File Table" thingy? Or else.)

Same question on any, Linux and MacOS computers. Like, how it goes in most common systems:

- Windows with NTFS
- Linux with Ext4
- OSX with HFS+
- etc

Comment: You usually make a directory on a filesystem. So the answer will vary per filesystem. It will also lead to a much to broad answer for this site which is focussed on practical solutions.

Comment: So how is that directory information stored? (Lets say on Windows)

Comment: Lets say on windows with ext2, on windows with FAT, on windows with NTFS, on windows with ZFS, on windows with ....

Comment: Let's say on windows with NTFS. Then?

Comment: Closed propriatary format IIRC. (In other word, I seem to remember that microsoft does not tell us how NTFS works).  May I suggest starting with a book which explains FAT, possibly as used from DOS. That is very simple but a god starting place.